# Trouble switching mobile device between two access points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

In order to extend my WIFI coverage I have recently added a new Access Point to my installation.

```
[Main Router]
192.168.10.1
  |       
  ├── /* Ethernet devices */
  ├── Wireless Access Point #1 - 192.168.10.15 - SSID1
  └── Wireless Access Point #2 - 192.168.10.10 - SSID2 <- New AP
        |       
        └── /* Some devices connected with Ethernet cables */
```

Main Router is the one and only DHCP server, giving IP addresses between 192.168.10.20 and 192.168.10.200.

Everything seems to work fine except when one mobile device, connected to SSID1, tries to connect to SSID2. Then strange things start to happens :

- sometimes it works perfectly, the network changes and my mobile device can access internet
- sometimes it works, but obtaining the address can take a couple minutes
- sometimes it fails, my phone showing a "Failed to obtain IP Address" message, if it fails several times in a row, switching off and on the AP seems to fix the problem

What I have tried so far:

- I have updated the main router DHCP configuration to give a static IP to the mobile device. This way it seems to never fail but most of the time it takes a couple minutes to obtain the IP address (which btw stays the same)
- I have updated my phone configuration to use a random MAC address when connecting to SSID2. This way it always work perfectly, but I have the feeling that this not a clean solution.

My feeling is that it's somehow related to the DHCP configuration but I can't find what has to be changed for this to work perfectly every times.

Any clues will help.

Thanks

PS: if that can be of interest the devices are

- TP-Link TL-R480T+ for the main router
- TP-Link TL-WA901ND for AP1
- TP-Link TD-W8960N for AP2

Comment: Your AP2 is a router. Have you explicitly disabled the DHCP server on it, and made sure the wan port is unplugged?

Comment: @davidgo : Yes DHCP server is disabled (on both IPv4 and IPv6 LAN Config tabs). There is nothing plugged on the LAN4/WAN port. Btw I did follow the following article to set-it up https://www.tp-link.com/it/support/faq/417/